# How to remove "view selection source" from Firefox v74.0 context menu?

Tags: firefox

How to remove "View Selection Source" from Firefox v74.0 context menu?

I never use that option in the FF context menu.

Its just taking up space that I have to mouse over 
so why have it there?

How to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not see the above in FF 74 (Ubuntu) or FF 68 (Kali).  Do you have Add-ons installed?  Can you edit your question and show a Screen Shot of how you see "View Selection Source"?

Comment: @John "View Selection Source" shows up when you select text and then right-click.

Comment: I see this now.  It one of a list of 10 or so items, so it is just part of the list.  I do not see a way to eliminate the one item.

Comment: "View Selection Source" is also part of FF 68 and so it is not a new thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of it by using `userChrome.css` :

```
#context-viewpartialsource-selection{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer to show how and where we can edit this stylesheet?

Comment: Hi, I added your fix by creating a userChrome.css to my FF user profile folder.  I edited it and added your fix.  But "View Selection Source" still appears.  Suggestions?  Thanks!